# Using Backbone Fetch Success Callback to Change Data Before Initializing View

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm looking for a way to intercept the value returned from a server when I fetch a backbone model (a collection, strictly speaking) from the server, then modify it before continuing. I would think that I could do something like this

```
SessionController.prototype._initPages = function() {
    return App.pages.fetch({
      reset: true,
      success: function(model, response, options) {
         //modify the contents of response
      }
};
```

And my modifications would be reflected in the model that's used to initialize the view.

However I was looking at the backbone source and I think I may have misunderstood something.

```
fetch: function(options) {
  options = options ? _.clone(options) : {};
  if (options.parse === void 0) options.parse = true;
  var success = options.success;
  var collection = this;
  options.success = function(resp) {
    var method = options.reset ? 'reset' : 'set';
    collection[method](resp, options);                 //this line updates the model
    if (success) success(collection, resp, options);   // my success callback 
    collection.trigger('sync', collection, resp, options);
  };
  wrapError(this, options);
  return this.sync('read', this, options);
}
```

For my needs, it seems the two commented lines need to be switched, though I assume I'm just misunderstanding how to use this feature.

How can I modify the server response before it becomes my model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could just override the `parse` function to modify your data as needed
http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse